# How to query the DbSets of all types that implement an interface?

Tags: entity-framework, reflection, interface, dbset

Many of my data models use this interface:

```
public interface IHasPrimaryImageProperty
{
    PrimaryImageDataModel PrimaryImage { get; set; }
    int? PrimaryImageId { get; set; }
}
```

Where `PrimaryImageDataModel` is:

```
public class PrimaryImageDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
    public int TotalItemsUsingImage { get; set; }
}
```

I want populate `PrimaryImageDataModel.TotalItemsUsingImage`, by performing counts on all data models that implement `IHasPrimaryImageProperty`.

So far I have managed to get a list of types that implement the `IHasPrimaryImageProperty`.

But I haven't been able to get the total for each Type.

Please see the example below for a demonstration of what I would like to acheive.

```
public static PrimaryImageDataModel GetImageUsageTotals(PrimaryImageDataModel image)
{
    var typesUsingImage = GetTypesWithPrimaryImageProperty();
    int totalUsingImage = 0;
    foreach (Type typeUsingImage in typesUsingImage)
    {
        // I WOULD LIKE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS
        totalForType = db.Set<typeUsingImage>()
            .Where(x => x.PrimaryImageId == image.Id)
            .Count()

        totalUsingImage += totalForType;
    }
    image.TotalItemsUsingImage = totalUsingImage;
    return image;
}


public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithPrimaryImageProperty()
{
    var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    foreach (Type type in currentAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IHasPrimaryImageProperty)))
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: I don't often say this, but in this case I'd really turn to a database view.

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry, my mum came round unexpectedly, had to abandon ship temporarily! It's EF6, but I see your answer covers both. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IQueryable is covariant.  See [Variance in Generic Interfaces (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces)  This allows an `IQueryable<SomeEntity>` to be cast to `IQueryable<InterfaceType>`, for interfaces implemented by that Entity type.

So if you put this method on your EF6 DbContext type:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>(Type EntityType)
{    
    return (IQueryable<T>)this.Set(EntityType);
}
```

Or like this for EF Core:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>(Type EntityType)
{

    var pq = from p in this.GetType().GetProperties()
             where p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
                && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)
                && p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0] ==  EntityType
             select p;
    var prop = pq.Single();

    return (IQueryable<T>)prop.GetValue(this);

}
```

Then you can write

```
foreach (Type typeUsingImage in typesUsingImage)
{
    // I WOULD LIKE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS
    totalForType = db.GetQuery<IHasPrimaryImageProperty>(typeUsingImage)
        .Where(x => x.PrimaryImageId == image.Id)
        .Count()

    totalUsingImage += totalForType;
}
```

Comment: 6 months later, and this answer has been so useful to me in the meantime. thank you

Answer (score 4):

The simplest I see (works in both EF6 and EF Core) is to create a generic method and call it via reflection.

For instance:

```
static int CountUsage<T>(DbContext db, PrimaryImageDataModel image)
    where T : class, IHasPrimaryImageProperty
{
    return db.Set<T>()
        .Where(x => x.PrimaryImageId == image.Id)
        .Count();
}

static readonly MethodInfo CountUsageMethodInfo = typeof(YourClass)
   .GetMethod("CountUsage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

public static PrimaryImageDataModel GetImageUsageTotals(PrimaryImageDataModel image)
{
    var args = new object[] { db, image };
    image.TotalItemsUsingImage = GetTypesWithPrimaryImageProperty()
        .Sum(type => (int)CountUsageMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null, args));
    return image;
}
```

Comment: I feel really bad for accepting the other answer, because your code does exactly what I want and is exactly the kind of thing I had *expected* to end up with. (Even though I wasn't sure how to write it).  But David's technique was the one I finally used so it only seemed correct to accept that.

Comment: Not a problem at all:) EF usually have issues with interfaces and changing the element type of the `IQueryable`, but the David's technique works for single aggregate queries like `Count`, and since it doesn't involve reflection (at least for EF6), it's just fine. Cheers.